# How can I use Multiple where clauses in a single mysql select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table called marksheet where I stored students' marks. I want to take out 20% of mark scored out of each unit exam, 30% out of each weekly test and 50% out of final exam. All the names of Unit Exams, Weekly Tests and Final exam are stored under one column name `Name_of_exam`. I can use

```
SELECT regd, 
       Sum(mark_score)/sum(Full_mark)*20 as scored 
FROM marksheet 
WHERE Name_of_exam='First Unit Exam' 
   OR Name_of_exam='Second Unit Exam' 
   OR Name_of_exam='Third Unit Exam' 
GROUP BY regd;
```

But the problem is that I have no idea how I can take out 30% of mark scored by students:
`Where (Name_of_exam='First Weekly Test` 
`or Name_of_exam='Second Weekly Test'`
`or Name_of_exam='Third Weekly Test')` 
and 50% of mark scored `Where Name_of_exam='Final Exam'`. in the same select statement as I have to do multiple where clauses. Please help. I have also attached here how I did the calculation in excel sheet.

[image: Image showing marksheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT names, subjects, 
SUM(
  CASE 
  WHEN name_of_exam = 'First Weekly Test' THEN (score/full_marks)*20 
  WHEN name_of_exam = 'First Unit Exam' THEN (score/full_marks)*30 
  WHEN name_of_exam = 'Final Unit Exam' THEN (score/full_marks)*50 
  END) AS scored
FROM marksheet
GROUP BY names, subjects
```

Comment: Thank you. But I also need to include Second Weekly Test, Third Weekly Test, Second Unit Exam and Third Unit Exam as well. Any way you give me ideas. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, it works, but I have to sum marks of First Weekly Test, Second Weekly Test and Third Weekly Test and take 20% out of it. This query return just one column of scored..

Comment: So you dont want one consolidated/total score, you want 3 scores for each student-subject group?

Comment: Yes Name, Subject, w_scored for weekly test, u-score for unit test and f-score for final exam.

Comment: Aziz Shaikh, I have just found the solution based on your query.. Thanks for giving me great idea...

Answer (score 3):

You can't use multiple `WHERE` parts, but always you can use logical operators to join conditions.

This `WHERE` will find results with score under your treshholds:

```
SELECT regd, names, subjects, 
  sum( score ) * (CASE WHEN (Name_of_exam='First Weekly Test or Name_of_exam='Second Weekly Test' or Name_of_exam='Third Weekly Test') THEN 0.2 
       WHEN ( Name_of_exam='First Unit Exam' or Name_of_exam='Second Unit Exam' OR Name_of_exam='Third Unit Exam')  THEN 0.3
       WHEN ( Name_of_exam='Final Exam' ) THEN 0.5 )
  AS scored
FROM marksheet
GROUP BY regd, names, subjects, test_type
```

Comment: @Kacer, I really appreciate your work, but this does not solve my problem. If you carefully read the question, you can see that I want to take out 20% and not less than 20, in addition I want to take out 30% from sum of first, second and third unit exam and of course 50% from final exam. Please can you write your code more clearer. So far your provided answer is not a valid sql statement as well.